# Module file was created by an older version of the compiler

Tags: ios, xcode, alamofire, carthage

Using Carthage to manage my dependencies, everything runs fine in the simulator.

However, when building for a device I get the following error:

[image]

```
Module File was created by an older version of the compiler; rebuild Alamofire and try again: .../DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iPhones...
```

I have tried what others suggested to similar issues: deleting my derived data, reinstalling Carthage and rebuilding the frameworks. However, the error has been persistent.

Comment: Are you using more than one Xcode on your Mac ?

Comment: @RahulKatariya No, just the latest official version of Xcode (not beta)

Comment: What do you see when you run xcode-select -p? It should be pointed at Xcode 7 if you want to use the frameworks in Xcode 7.

Comment: @RahulKatariya it's pointing to 7.3

Comment: Did you use carthage update with --no-use-binaries option ?

Comment: @RahulKatariya yes, I tried that and got the same result unfortunately

Comment: Can you show your cartfile.private file?

Comment: @RahulKatariya Do you mean my Cartfile? That just has: github "Alamofire/Alamofire" ~> 3.3
github "SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON"

Comment: I can only think of 3 options right now. GoodLuck :)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Are you using the right version of xcodebuild? What do you see when you run xcode-select -p? It should be pointed at Xcode 7 if you want to use the frameworks in Xcode 7.

Remove all the derive data `rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ && carthage build`

Also, When you use `carthage update` **without --no-use-binaries** option then it downloads the pre built frameworks which may be built using the old version of xcodebuild.

Alternative way is to use `carthage update --no-use-binaries`. This way it will compile all the frameworks with the latest Xcode build installed on your Mac.

Comment: I followed these steps (using carthage build) and it built successfully.

Comment: Thank you, that worked for me. But, since I'm using CocoaPods instead of Carthage, i had to do a `pod deintegrate` and `pod update` to reinstall the frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

I am using cocoapods.I just right-click the wrong framework,show it in Finder,remove it,and build the project again,solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try rebuilding the framework by command line:

- Open Terminal
- cd project/directory
- **carthage build**

then clean the xcode project and run!