# SwiftyJSON supported in Xcode 8 and iOS 10?

Tags: ios, xcode, swifty-json, ios10, xcode8

I recently upgraded my Swift iOS application from `Xcode7` to `Xcode8` and deployment platform from `iOS 9.3` to `iOS 10`. My application started breaking with errors like this:

> Module file was created by an older version of the compiler: rebuild
>   'SwiftyJSON' and try again.

I Googled around and found this link on SO [Module file was created by an older version of the compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36661635/module-file-was-created-by-an-older-version-of-the-compiler).  Followed the instructions and removed the derived data and rebuilt using `carthage update --no-use-binaries` command. But the application still fails to build and complains about the error message mentioned above.

Is `SwiftyJSON` supported by `Xcode 8` and `iOS 10`?

Comment: Have you looked on [github](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON)? If there is any support there is a note.

Comment: Yes, i looked into this https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON#requirements and I do not see any mention of Xcode 8 and iOS 10

Comment: Right after the summary there is *For Swift3 support, take a look at the [swift3 beta branch](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON/tree/swift3)*

Comment: Ok, but my application is still using Swift 2 and how would I add this new dependency through carthage ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SwiftyJSON [now supports Swift 3](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON/issues/647).

`pod 'SwiftyJSON', '3.0.0'`

Answer (score 5):

At the time of writing this: no.

But there is a fork of the `swift3`-branch which is working with the GM seeds.

https://github.com/acegreen/SwiftyJSON

Comment: Yes, I see it there but not sure how to integrate it with carthage or cocoapod. Can you please guide ?

Comment: @user2325154 In Cocoapods, you can import it like this: `pod "SwiftyJSON", :git => "https://github.com/acegreen/SwiftyJSON.git", :branch => "swift3"`

Comment: Hello i installed the swift 3 branch but i still have the "Module file was created by an older version of the compiler..." do i have to delete the old dependency first? I use cocoapods. I tried pod update and pod install both later on give me the same error on xcode 8.

Answer (score 0):

pod 'SwiftyJSON', git: 'https://github.com/BaiduHiDeviOS/SwiftyJSON.git', branch: 'swift3'

You will get a lot off error after that please delete your derived data folder. And build it. All works fine

Answer (score 0):

pod 'SwiftyJSON', git: 'https://github.com/BaiduHiDeviOS/SwiftyJSON.git', branch: 'swift3'

Comment: Perhaps you could be a bit more explicity about the proposed solution?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by removing the named file, e.g. /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-aprzyqkcjkpzgaedatcseafvznfq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Alamofire.framework/Modules/Alamofire.swiftmodule/x86_64.swiftmodule

Not positive I'm on the right path, because the file was NOT regenerated, but I appear to be past the problem for now, and on to ordinary Swift3 conversion errors in my own code.