# Swift 3 upgrade error: Module file was created by an older version of the compiler

Tags: swift3, xcode8

Im using Cocoapods as my dependency managment, but I am getting error every time i build now.

"Module file was created by an older version of the compiler"

And I only have xcode 8 installed, did a upgrade from xcode 7.

Comment: Please take a look at this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36661635/module-file-was-created-by-an-older-version-of-the-compiler

Answer (score 1):

Deleting ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData fix this issue.