# Can't migrate to 3.0 pods libraries

Tags: swift, cocoapods, swift3

I use [Kanna](https://github.com/tid-kijyun/Kanna) and [Reachability](https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift) libraries. And seems they already migrated to swift 3. I use [Cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org/):

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '8.0'
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
use_frameworks!

target 'MyProj' do
pod 'Kanna', '~> 2.0.0'
pod 'ReachabilitySwift', '~> 3'
end

post_install do |installer|
installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.0'
    end
end
```

end

Got error when do import:

```
import Kanna
import ReachabilitySwift
```

> Module compiled with Swift 2.3 cannot be imported in Swift 3.0

Flag: `Use legacy swift versions` everywhere set to `No`

Comment: What is the output when you run pod install or pod update from the command line?

Comment: all is ok:   Pod installation complete! There are 7 dependencies from the Podfile and 17
  total pods installed.

Comment: Glad to hear it. I had a lot of trouble with a similar problem last week.

Comment: @Sparky what solution ?:) up my question please) Because i tried all links already, nothing help.

Comment: apologies, I thought your message meant you had solved the issue! I have upvoted your question as I'm not sure what the problem is in your case.

Comment: @Sparky but what the solution in yours ?

Comment: The reason I asked for the output from pod install was because my Pods weren't even updating when I changed the podfile for the new version. I actually ended up using Carthage as an alternative. Are your pods available on Carthage instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36661635/module-file-was-created-by-an-older-version-of-the-compiler?answertab=active#tab-top). Need to delete `rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/` This folder was cached.